# Typing "stack" results in "sxtazck," (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: keyboard, input

Very annoying issue: keys are inserted while I type text. For example, typing "a" gives "az" as seen on the "Keyboard Layout Map" below:

[image: Keyboard Layout Map]

All was fine yesterday.
PL>EAZSXE HEL>P!!! (text inserted while typing "PLEASE HELP!!!")

```
Typing "qwertyuiopasdfgbhjklzxcvbnm" results in:
       "qwertyuiopazsxdcfvgbhjmk,l.zxcvbnm"
```

Comment: Did you spill anything in your keyboard?  Sounds like a defective keyboard since it is reading the middle and bottom row of keys at the same time.

Comment: No. Thaznk, you fvor the quesxtion.

Comment: is it a notebook keyboard or a separate keyboard for a laptop? have you tried with a different keyboard, if the second case?

Comment: Hi Lorenz - I tried a new keyboard (same model borrowed from nearby desk) and it resolved the issue! Thanks a lot for the prompt questions - you rule guys!

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is the simplest one :-D

Answer (score 1):

I am very sorry to have wasted your time: the issue "magically" corrected itself once I switched the keyboard. Thanks again for the great response time guys!!